# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate returnDocument not working

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following code that returns findOneAndUpdate response. But `returnDocument: "after"` not working properly when I'm using it with `arrayFilters`. If I remove arrayFilters it works fine. What causes this or is there a better way to get modified document in response?

```
const addStartingCards = async (lobbyId) => {
    const res = await db.findOneAndUpdate(
        { lobbyId: lobbyId },
        {
            $push: {
                "seats.$[el].cards": {
                    $each: [Math.floor(Math.random() * 52), Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            arrayFilters: [
                {
                    "el.status": true,
                }
            ]
        },
        { returnOriginal: false, returnDocument: "after" });
    return (res.value);
};
```

Comment: Does this make it work, `{arrayFilters: [{"el.status": true}], returnDocument: "after" }`?  I.e., I think there is just one "options document" so `arrayFilters` and `returnDocument` go i it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rickhg12hs suggested in comments, this is the correct format to use them together;

```
{arrayFilters: [{"el.status": true}], returnDocument: "after" }
```